# Inherit class with template function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I would like to create a base class that will be inherited by other objects so that they can be stored in the same container.  This base class will contain a templated method that defines the function as a setter or getter used for accessing a buffer in a multithreaded system.  I want to do something like this guy did but not really sure how to implement [Linky](http://www.lateral.co.za/5mins/060106_5mins_template_return_types.pdf).  Also I would like to be able to have the function in the base to be virtual and define the functionality in the derived classes, I know you can't actually have a virtual template function but is there a way to code it in a way that it acts like the concept of a virtual template function.  Below is a crude example on how I would like the layout to be.  The do_work method with be called through a callback.  The callback is passed to the thread as a argument.

```
class A {
    template<typename R, typename P>
    virtual R do_work(P param) = 0;
}

class B : public A {
    template<void,int> // declare as setter
    R do_work(P param){/*do something*/ return R;}

}

class C : public A {
    template<int,void> // declare as getter
    R do_work(P param){/*do something*/ return R;}

}
```

Comment: The question in the linked article, how to do something different if the first template argument is `void`. I think the answer would be to use `boost::enable_if` to enable-disable of one of two alternative implementations. - Not sure though, how your question is connected to that.

Comment: would it be possible to write a macro that test if R is equal to void and if so use this function if not use the function with a templated return type.

Comment: Another problem: you are not expecting `P` to be void, giving signatures like `R do_work(void param)`?

Comment: yea didn't think of that.  I have two cases that I need to cover: "do_work with a return and no parameters" and "do_work with no return and one parameter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended making two helper classes, a consumer class and producer class that inherit the base class.  The base class contains a enum define define whether the derived classes are what functionality.  This enum value is set during the base class constructor call.  The helper classes contain the appropriate version of the virtual do_work function that I want (one void w/ some input type and one some return type).  When these objects are placed in the container they are casted as the base class and when they are launched in the appropriate generic thread worker function they are either casted to the producer helper class or consumer helper class.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a problem with A being a template argument of do_work in class A: this doesn't actually make sense.

R is not defined anywhere in B or C and your specialisation syntax is wrong.

do_work will not be polymorphic as it is not virtual, so if you have a collection of A pointers it will only ever call the A version, never the B or C one, even if they are better matches.

Comment: sorry for the bad syntax I just have no idea how to actually code it so I just threw something together to best illustrate what I want to happen in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for using template programming for efficiency and generality, but perhaps you should implement this with virtual functions first. I find it helpful to get *something* working cleanly and correcting before writing a templated version.

Folks here may give you a better answer as well if you have a working non template function.

Besides, if you are going to call this via a callback or pointer to function, you will lose the perf that I think you are trying to gain with a template based solution.

Comment: I guess I could do something like this virtual void do_work(void *retrn, void *param)=0; and declare the proper casting and functionality inside the derived classes

Comment: All I'm suggesting is that you look at the functionality first and get something working, before applying templates.  I've found this makes it easier and I think you'll get specific feedback here if you edit your response with a working solution.

Comment: Using void * may or may not be the right thing to do, it probably is not, but if it is you probably want to make it private and get a public templated function to do the casting then call the method. That makes the class at least type-safe for users.